# sort combobox html or php

Tags: html, combobox

I have a small question to ask all of you. How can I sort a combobox from html or php? I have the values from the database, but I was wondering if I could do it directly from html to sort it.

Comment: use Jquery Dom element to make this possible

Answer (score 0):

Why not sort the data directly with a SQL query?
http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/order_by.php